# Proving a determinant inequality

Tags: matrices, determinant

Let $A$ be a square matrix in $M_n(\mathbb R)$. Prove that:
$$det(A^2+I_n) \ge 0$$

I wrote  $A^2+I_n=A^2 I_n+I_n=I_n(A^2+1)$:
$$det(I_n)\cdot det(A^2+1)=det(A^2+1)$$

How can I prove that is $\ge 0$ ? Thank you.

Comment: $A^2+1$ doesn't make sense, unless maybe $n=1$.

Answer (score 8):

The problem in the OP approach is that we don't know what $A^2+1$ is.

It's better to use complex numbers and the relatioships:

- $A^2+I_n=(A-iI_n)(A+iI_n)$, and
- $\det(\overline B)=\overline{\det B}$ for any complex square matrix $B$.

Comment: To confirm, the bar means complex conjugate in this context?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$